# Ingress kubernetes not available

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to upgrade helm package with the following configuration:

```
    ingress:
      hostName: jenkins.mydomain.com
      enabled: true
      tls:
      - secretName: mydomain-tls
        hosts:
          - jenkins.mydomain.com
```

I am getting error:

```
UPGRADE FAILED
  ROLLING BACK
  Error: no Ingress with the name "jenkins" found
  Error: UPGRADE FAILED: no Ingress with the name "jenkins" found
```

When I run `kubectl get ing -n infrastructure`, I can see

```
NAME          HOSTS                ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
jenkins       jenkins.mydomain.com             80, 443   3h
```

My ingress looks config like this:

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2021-02-05T15:22:34Z
  generation: 2
  name: jenkins
  namespace: infrastructure
  resourceVersion: "201126655"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/infrastructure/ingresses/jenkins
  uid: f8f2438a-67c5-11eb-83f4-02dd174aaaa7
spec:
  rules:
  - host: jenkins.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - jenkins.mydomain.com
    secretName: mydomain-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```

```
Upgrading release=jenkins, chart=myapp/jenkins
UPGRADE FAILED
ROLLING BACK
Error: no Ingress with the name "jenkins" found


FAILED RELEASES:
NAME
jenkins
in ./helmfile.yaml: failed processing release jenkins: command "/usr/local/bin/helm" exited with non-zero status:

PATH:
  /usr/local/bin/helm

ARGS:
  0: /usr/local/bin/helm (19 bytes)
  1: upgrade (7 bytes)
  2: --install (9 bytes)
  3: --reset-values (14 bytes)
  4: jenkins (7 bytes)
  5: myapp/jenkins (15 bytes)
  6: --version (9 bytes)
  7: 0.35.17 (7 bytes)
  8: --namespace (11 bytes)
  9: infrastructure (14 bytes)
  10: --values (8 bytes)
  11: /var/folders/ht/h_5qbgyx1w9c_fwd5hrg0mhr0000gn/T/helmfile840999588/infrastructure-jenkins-values-6998bfbb68 (107 bytes)
  12: --values (8 bytes)
  13: /var/folders/ht/h_5qbgyx1w9c_fwd5hrg0mhr0000gn/T/helmfile406900659/infrastructure-jenkins-values-55c4c47467 (107 bytes)
  14: --values (8 bytes)
  15: /var/folders/ht/h_5qbgyx1w9c_fwd5hrg0mhr0000gn/T/secret465583478 (64 bytes)
  16: --values (8 bytes)
  17: /var/folders/ht/h_5qbgyx1w9c_fwd5hrg0mhr0000gn/T/secret417700445 (64 bytes)
  18: --values (8 bytes)
  19: /var/folders/ht/h_5qbgyx1w9c_fwd5hrg0mhr0000gn/T/secret246274072 (64 bytes)

ERROR:
  exit status 1

EXIT STATUS
  1
```

I am running the command `helmfile --namespace=infrastructure --helm-binary=/usr/local/bin/helm --selector name=jenkins sync --skip-deps`

This is what I can see if I describe ingress

```
kubectl describe ingress jenkins -n infrastructure
Name:             jenkins
Namespace:        infrastructure
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  mydomain-tls terminates jenkins.myapp.com
Rules:
  Host                Path  Backends
  ----                ----  --------
  jenkins.myapp.com  
                         myapp:8080 (<none>)
Annotations:
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age              From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----             ----                      -------
  Normal  UPDATE  6m (x2 over 1d)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress infrastructure/jenkins
  Normal  UPDATE  6m (x2 over 1d)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress infrastructure/jenkins
```

My helm chart:

```
jenkins:
  Master:
    UseSecurity: true
    HostNetworking: false
    AdminUser: gruba
    AdminPassword: baba
    ImageTag: "lts"
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "50m"
        memory: "256Mi"
      limits:
        cpu: "2000m"
        memory: "2048Mi"
    ingress:
      hostName: jenkins.myapp.com
      enabled: true
      tls:
      - secretName: myappcom-tls
        hosts:
          - jenkins.myapp.com
    AdditionalConfig: {}
#    ServiceType: ClusterIP
    NodePort: 32331
    # Enable Kubernetes Liveness and Readiness Probes
    # ~ 2 minutes to allow Jenkins to restart when upgrading plugins. Set ReadinessTimeout to be shorter than LivenessTimeout.
    HealthProbes: true
    HealthProbesLivenessTimeout: 90
    HealthProbesReadinessTimeout: 60
    HealthProbeLivenessFailureThreshold: 12
    SlaveListenerPort: 50000
    DisabledAgentProtocols:
      - JNLP-connect
      - JNLP2-connect
    CSRF:
      DefaultCrumbIssuer:
        Enabled: true
        ProxyCompatability: true
    CLI: false
    # Kubernetes service type for the JNLP slave service
    # SETTING THIS TO "LoadBalancer" IS A HUGE SECURITY RISK: https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/1341
    SlaveListenerServiceType: ClusterIP
    SlaveListenerServiceAnnotations: {}
    LoadBalancerSourceRanges:
    - 0.0.0.0/0

    OverwritePlugins: true
    InstallPlugins:
      - workflow-cps-global-lib:2.17
      - blueocean-config:1.24.3
      - blueocean-git-pipeline:1.24.3
      - blueocean-bitbucket-pipeline:1.24.3
      - cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source:2.9.4
      - jaxb:2.3.0.1
      - blueocean-display-url:2.4.0
      - aws-java-sdk:1.11.854
      - workflow-cps:2.84
      - sse-gateway:1.24
      - role-strategy:3.1
      - structs:1.20
      - git:4.4.5
      - blueocean-executor-info:1.24.3
      - pipeline-stage-tags-metadata:1.7.2
      - checks-api:1.1.0
      - kubernetes-client-api:4.11.1
      - blueocean-jira:1.24.3
      - bootstrap4-api:4.5.3-1
      - plugin-util-api:1.4.0
      - github-branch-source:2.9.1
      - workflow-api:2.40
      - antisamy-markup-formatter:2.1
      - blueocean-web:1.24.3
      - kubernetes:1.27.3
      - pubsub-light:1.13
      - echarts-api:4.9.0-2
      - aws-credentials:1.28
      - junit:1.43
      - workflow-basic-steps:2.21
      - mailer:1.32.1
      - pipeline-milestone-step:1.3.1
      - job-dsl:1.77
      - aws-secrets-manager-credentials-provider:0.5.0
      - pipeline-model-definition:1.7.2
      - pipeline-model-extensions:1.7.2
      - bouncycastle-api:2.18
      - authentication-tokens:1.4
      - pipeline-graph-analysis:1.10
      - timestamper:1.11.8
      - blueocean:1.24.3
      - ws-cleanup:0.38
      - pipeline-stage-step:2.5
      - blueocean-pipeline-api-impl:1.24.3
      - ssh-credentials:1.18.1
      - pipeline-input-step:2.12
      - pipeline-rest-api:2.18
      - pipeline-model-api:1.7.2
      - blueocean-personalization:1.24.3
      - ghprb:1.42.1
      - durable-task:1.35
      - github-oauth:0.33
      - mapdb-api:1.0.9.0
      - handy-uri-templates-2-api:2.1.8-1.0
      - workflow-aggregator:2.6
      - blueocean-jwt:1.24.3
      - docker-workflow:1.24
      - blueocean-events:1.24.3
      - jdk-tool:1.4
      - blueocean-i18n:1.24.3
      - branch-api:2.6.1
      - ant:1.11
      - ssh-slaves:1.31.2
      - font-awesome-api:5.15.1-1
      - blueocean-rest:1.24.3
      - matrix-auth:2.6.4
      - matrix-project:1.18
      - conditional-buildstep:1.3.6
      - jsch:0.1.55.2
      - jenkins-design-language:1.24.3
      - jira:3.1.1
      - pam-auth:1.6
      - pipeline-build-step:2.13
      - blueocean-rest-impl:1.24.3
      - git-client:3.5.1
      - ssh-agent:1.20
      - simple-theme-plugin:0.6
      - parameterized-trigger:2.39
      - docker-java-api:3.1.5.2
      - git-server:1.9
      - resource-disposer:0.14
      - blueocean-dashboard:1.24.3
      - slack:2.43
      - script-security:1.75
      - ldap:1.26
      - github-api:1.116
      - handlebars:1.1.1
      - blueocean-commons:1.24.3
      - configuration-as-code:1.45
      - workflow-durable-task-step:2.35
      - variant:1.3
      - maven-plugin:3.8
      - token-macro:2.12
      - aws-bucket-credentials:1.0.0
      - subversion:2.13.1
      - run-condition:1.3
      - popper-api:1.16.0-7
      - apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api:4.5.10-2.0
      - favorite:2.3.2
      - workflow-step-api:2.23
      - plain-credentials:1.7
      - email-ext:2.78
      - blueocean-pipeline-editor:1.24.3
      - blueocean-pipeline-scm-api:1.24.3
      - docker-commons:1.17
      - cloudbees-folder:6.14
      - lockable-resources:2.10
      - javadoc:1.6
      - pipeline-stage-view:2.18
      - kubernetes-credentials:0.7.0
      - github:1.32.0
      - scm-api:2.6.4
      - mercurial:2.11
      - jquery3-api:3.5.1-2
      - workflow-job:2.40
      - docker-plugin:1.2.1
      - workflow-multibranch:2.22
      - okhttp-api:3.14.9
      - ansicolor:0.7.3
      - snakeyaml-api:1.27.0
      - trilead-api:1.0.12
      - jackson2-api:2.11.3
      - command-launcher:1.5
      - gradle:1.36
      - jquery-detached:1.2.1
      - blueocean-github-pipeline:1.24.3
      - workflow-scm-step:2.11
      - momentjs:1.1.1
      - blueocean-core-js:1.24.3
      - credentials-binding:1.24
      - htmlpublisher:1.23
      - credentials:2.3.13
      - pipeline-github-lib:1.0
      - display-url-api:2.3.3
      - build-timeout:1.20
      - workflow-support:3.5
      - blueocean-autofavorite:1.2.4
      - ace-editor:1.1
      - pipeline-aws:1.42
      - job-import-plugin:3.4
    JCasC:
      enabled: true
      PluginVersion: 1.36
      # SupportPluginVersion: 1.33
      ConfigScripts:
        # moved to casc.yaml file
    # List of groovy init scripts to be executed during Jenkins master start
    InitScripts:
      - |
        import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader
        import javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement

        def jobScript = new File('/usr/share/jenkins/seed-job.groovy')
        def jobManagement = new JenkinsJobManagement(System.out, [:], new File('.'))

        println "Creating the seed job"
        new DslScriptLoader(jobManagement).with {
            runScript(jobScript.text)
        }
    #  - |
    #    print 'adding global pipeline libraries, register properties, bootstrap jobs...'
    # Kubernetes secret that contains a 'credentials.xml' for Jenkins
    # CredentialsXmlSecret: jenkins-credentials
    # Kubernetes secret that contains files to be put in the Jenkins 'secrets' directory,
    # useful to manage encryption keys used for credentials.xml for instance (such as
    # master.key and hudson.util.Secret)
    SecretsFilesSecret: jenkins-secrets
    # Jenkins XML job configs to provision
    # Jobs: |-
    #   test: |-
    #     <<xml here>>
    CustomConfigMap: false
    # By default, the configMap is only used to set the initial config the first time
    # that the chart is installed.  Setting `OverwriteConfig` to `true` will overwrite
    # the jenkins config with the contents of the configMap every time the pod starts.
    OverwriteConfig: false
    # Node labels and tolerations for pod assignment
    # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector
    # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#taints-and-tolerations-beta-feature
    NodeSelector:
      nodePool: infrastructure
    Tolerations: {}
    PodAnnotations: {}

  Agent:
    Enabled: true
    Image: jenkins/jnlp-slave
    ImageTag: 3.35-5
    CustomJenkinsLabels: []
  # ImagePullSecret: jenkins
    Component: "jenkins-slave"
    Privileged: false
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "200m"
        memory: "256Mi"
      limits:
        cpu: "200m"
        memory: "256Mi"
    # You may want to change this to true while testing a new image
    AlwaysPullImage: false
    # Controls how slave pods are retained after the Jenkins build completes
    # Possible values: Always, Never, OnFailure
    PodRetention: Never
    # You can define the volumes that you want to mount for this container
    # Allowed types are: ConfigMap, EmptyDir, HostPath, Nfs, Pod, Secret
    # Configure the attributes as they appear in the corresponding Java class for that type
    # https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/csanchez/jenkins/plugins/kubernetes/volumes
    volumes:
    # - type: Secret
    #   secretName: mysecret
    #   mountPath: /var/myapp/mysecret
    NodeSelector: {}
    # Key Value selectors. Ex:
    # jenkins-agent: v1

  Persistence:
    Enabled: true
    ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
    ## Requires Persistence.Enabled: true
    ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
    # ExistingClaim:

    ## jenkins data Persistent Volume Storage Class
    ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
    ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
    ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
    ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
    ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
    ##
    StorageClass: aws-efs

    Annotations: {}
    AccessMode: ReadWriteOnce
    Size: 4Gi
    volumes:
    - name: secrets
      secret:
        secretName: jenkins-secrets
        items:
        - key: github_ssh_key
          path: github_ssh_key
    - name: configs
      configMap:
        name: jenkins-configs
        items:
        - key: seed-job.groovy
          path: seed-job.groovy
    mounts:
    - mountPath: /run/secrets/github_ssh_key
      name: secrets
      subPath: github_ssh_key
    - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/seed-job.groovy
      name: configs
      subPath: seed-job.groovy

  NetworkPolicy:
    # Enable creation of NetworkPolicy resources.
    Enabled: false
    # For Kubernetes v1.4, v1.5 and v1.6, use 'extensions/v1beta1'
    # For Kubernetes v1.7, use 'networking.k8s.io/v1'
    ApiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

  ## Install Default RBAC roles and bindings
  rbac:
    install: true
    serviceAccountName: jenkins
    # Role reference
    roleRef: cluster-admin
    # Role kind (RoleBinding or ClusterRoleBinding)
    roleBindingKind: ClusterRoleBinding
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this ingress. Any idea what can be wrong here?

Comment: Did you create the ingress manually and then applied the helm upgrade? Can you post the helm command with --dry-run and --debug? This should show what are the resources that the Chart is trying to install

Comment: @AndD I am running this command: ` helmfile --namespace=infrastructure --helm-binary=/usr/local/bin/helm --selector name=jenkins sync   --skip-deps` (no --dry-run and --debug options there :/ )

I have updated the output with more details

Comment: @AndD I expect that ingress was there before (since all other subdomains are defined like that). But, I can see that ingress was made yesterday - when I experienced the problem.

Comment: Do you use [this Helm Chart](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts) ?
Can you provide entire configuration (values.yml file) ?

Comment: @matt_j Yes, I am using that chart. I have provided values.yml

Comment: I think it is related to your issue https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/4871.
For that reason it's good to use `--cleanup-on-fail=true` flag.

Comment: any progress ?
Does the link I posted in the previous comment answer your question ?